# I can't get the width of a div in javascript

Tags: javascript

My code positions a div where my mouse is at the time and is supposed to move the div to the left the same amount as its width if it is too close to the right side of the page. But I can't seem to get the width of the div. Here is my code:

```
function position(e) {
  document.getElementById(tt).style.visibility = "visible";
  if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
    var winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
    var winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
  }
  if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
    l = e.pageX;
    u = e.pageY;
  } else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
    l = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    u = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
  var divL = document.getElementById(tt).style.width;
  if ((winW - l) <= 320) {
    l = l - divL;
  }
  document.getElementById(tt).style.top = (u + 10) + 'px';
  document.getElementById(tt).style.left = (l + 10) + 'px';

}
```

Comment: Which line gives you a result you don't expect, and what is the expected value and the actual returned value on that line?

Comment: i think it is this var divL = document.getElementById(tt).style.width;
and i think it is giving me a null

Comment: for the css i only have a max width set but something is inside the div so it should have a width right?

Comment: If tt isn't a variable declared in a greater scope, then your problem is not using quotes around it.

Comment: `document.getElementById(tt).style.width` will only give you the CSS-defined width. If it is not pre-defined then you'll get null.

Comment: @user1804234 I would suggest using jQuery and the `width()` function. But I suggest jQuery for almost everything.

Comment: is there any other way beside jquery?

Comment: @user1804234 presumably, explicitly defining the css would work, too.

Comment: You can always try getComputedStyle with getPropertyValue, but support isn't universal for older browsers and it may not get you anything that style.width wouldn't get you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

Comment: @user1804234 but I guess that wouldn't work if it's a dynamic width, which it sounds like it is. There's also what kinakuta said, but I typically suggest against that, as it doesn't work at all in ie6 and it's a bit fuzzy in ie7. I'd use jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var width = document.getElementById(tt).offsetWidth;
```